# AWS and Rails: The authorization header is malformed; the Credential is mal-formed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access my S3 bucket from a production server. Everything works fine in development, however in my prod console I am getting:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting "<YOUR-AKID>/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request".
```

My code:

```
class AwsFileDownloader
  def initialize(args)
    @s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
    @aws_file_path = ...
  end

  def get_file
    temp_file = File.new('temp.csv', 'r+')
    @s3.get_object({bucket: Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket, key: @aws_file_path}, target: temp_file)
    ...
  end
end
```

My aws initializer (which seems to work fine in both environments):

```
require 'aws-sdk'

Aws.config.update({
  region: Rails.application.secrets.aws_region,
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(Rails.application.secrets.access_key_id, Rails.application.secrets.secret_access_key)
})
```

appreciate any advice!

Comment: Find a way to look at the actual request that's being sent.  The solution should be intuitive at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things to check:

- bucket ACLs and bucket policies. Does production match dev?
- do any of your keys contain slashes, that could be incorrectly parsed?
- are your dev and production regions different? Does it make a difference if you try a different region?

Comment: It is unbelievable to me that Amazon is generating keys that are not URL safe.

Comment: could you please also tell what should someone do if the keys contain a slash?

Answer (score 60):

This answer is very late but maybe someone will find it useful. The above error is caused when you switch up the `AWS KEY ID` and the `AWS ACCESS KEY`.

Use the correct credential in the right place and it should fix your issue.

Comment: Big thanks! I used the secret key for both login and secret.

Comment: That's correct, worked for me, thanks. It was a silly copy-paste mistake

Comment: I have stuck for whole day, really really thanks!

Comment: you are my hero!

Comment: Inspirational!!! It's difficult to find mistakes like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests the credentials is not being set correctly. One possible reason (since in works in development environment) is that the config variables access_key_id and secret_access_key might be environment specific.

Comment: thanks for the take but definitely that is not the problem, as I can see the aws vars from the prod console.

Answer (score 0):

*for Windows Users*
I got the same issue over and over again, even after copying the correct credentials. Turns out Windows Bash was not accepting CTRL+C and CTRL+V for copy and paste. only right clicking and copy paste option worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I was writing tests using the RestAssured library and made a GET request to a signed URL obtained from an API call. The URL had the slashes from `"<YOUR-AKID>/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request"` url encoded, then RestAssured encoded the percent signs from the already url encoded URL. So I ended up with something like `%252F`instead of `%2F` in place of the slashes. My fix was to decode the signed url before passing it to RestAssured.

```java
given(requestSpec)
  .when()
  .get(URLDecoder.decode(s3SignedUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, got the same error but the problem was I interchanged the values of access key and secret key by mistake.

Comment: Duplicate of top comment.